# WSO2 IS 5.1.0 - Error while updating Service Provider using Soap

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

While updating permissions to service provider, sometimes leaf nodes are not getting deleted.

For example,

following permissions exist in Service Provider,

```
BILL/ADD
BILL/REMOVE
REPORT/ADD
REPORT/REMOVE
```

on update with only following permission,

```
REPORT/ADD
REPORT/REMOVE
```

**Sample SOAP Call:**

**Endpoint:**

services/IdentityApplicationManagementService.IdentityApplicationManagementServiceHttpsSoap11Endpoint/

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://org.apache.axis2/xsd" xmlns:xsd1="http://model.common.application.identity.carbon.wso2.org/xsd">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <xsd:updateApplication>
         <xsd:serviceProvider>
            <xsd1:applicationID>1</xsd1:applicationID>
            <xsd1:applicationName>SP1</xsd1:applicationName>
            <xsd1:permissionAndRoleConfig>
               <xsd1:permissions>
                  <xsd1:value>REPORT/ADD</xsd1:value>
               </xsd1:permissions>
               <xsd1:permissions>
                  <xsd1:value>REPORT/REMOVE</xsd1:value>
               </xsd1:permissions>
            </xsd1:permissionAndRoleConfig>
            <xsd1:inboundProvisioningConfig>
            </xsd1:inboundProvisioningConfig>
            <xsd1:outboundProvisioningConfig>
            </xsd1:outboundProvisioningConfig>
         </xsd:serviceProvider>
      </xsd:updateApplication>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

BILL/ADD & BILL/REMOVE has been removed. But after successful update, "BILL" still exist in permission list.

After Update:

```
BILL
REPORT/ADD
REPORT/REMOVE
```

And on sometimes, adding/removing multiple permission collapses the other permission nodes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of updating the application, add/remove resource in the application will resolve the issue.

For example for application sample,

**SOAP API URL :**

/services/ResourceAdminService.ResourceAdminServiceHttpsSoap12Endpoint/

**Add Resource:**

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:ser="http://services.resource.registry.carbon.wso2.org">
   <soap:Header/>
   <soap:Body>
      <ser:addCollection>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <ser:parentPath>/_system/governance/permission/applications/sample/REPORT</ser:parentPath>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <ser:collectionName>CREATE</ser:collectionName>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <ser:mediaType>?</ser:mediaType>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <ser:description>?</ser:description>
      </ser:addCollection>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

**Delete Resource :**

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:ser="http://services.resource.registry.carbon.wso2.org">
   <soap:Header/>
   <soap:Body>
      <ser:delete>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <ser:pathToDelete>/_system/governance/permission/applications/sample/BILL</ser:pathToDelete>
      </ser:delete>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```